# How many 4 letter words can you form using different letters from the word FAILURE so that F and I arent included in any of them

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations, combinations

How many  4 letter words can you form using different letters from the word FAILURE so that F and I aren't included in any of the arrangements ( words don't have to be meaningful)

Alright I thought that I should only provide you with the question but here are my attempts of solving it :

I discarded the letters F and I in my first attempt
( 5×4×3×2) = 120 four letter words

Unfortunately my answer is wrong because the right answer should be 600
but I can't get the correct steps.

So I tried again this time subtracting the arrangements that include the letter "F" but don't include the letter "I" ( F A L U R E) and arrangements that include the letter "I" without including the letter "F" ( A I L U R E )
from all possible arrangements: (7×6×5×4)-(6×5×4×3) + (6×5×4×3) = 840 - 360 +360 = 840 -720 = 120: again this answer is wrong.

And I think I have an explanation for that because I can get a word combination like  ALUR (doesn't include the letter F) or AELU (Doesn't include the letter I).

Then I realized that 840(possible arrangements) ÷ 7 (letters of the word FAILURE)  = 120 so each letter is included 120 times
120×5 (all letters without the F and I) = 600

Now I know that 600 is for sure the correct answer but I don't know how to solve it using the main topic of my class " counting principle" and I'm wondering if any one knows the correct way to do so.

I saw a teacher's solution and it was 840-(4×5×3×4) 840-240= 600.

I reached out to the teacher to know the steps but they didn't reply back.

Comment: Please show your efforts in solving this question. This is not "do my homework" site.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a FAILURE on the context count.

Comment: Thanks for making the edits to your question: it's much better now.

Answer (score 0):

Since we have been given that F,I are eliminated, one can simply say that we have to choose $4$ letters out of $5$, i.e., ALURE.

Thus we get the answer as $5 \choose 4 $$\cdot 4!=120$

Thus there are $120$ such words.

Comment: please don't answer poor standard questions

Comment: Also, is REAL the same word as LEAR?

Comment: @Patricio thanks for pointing out that mistake. I forgot to consider the order.

Comment: Let's at least **try** not to make this a site where people can come to cheat on their homework or exams.